# How can I ensure the image exported from Print Composer is accurate?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, image, qgis-2.12

I'm using QGIS version 2.12.2, and using print composer to export my map to an image file (I've tried pdf as well). In the print composer it displays fine - just a basemap overlayed with land type data. However, as soon as I export the map, the basemap and the overlayed data are misaligned; rivers are categorised as fields etc. How can I ensure that the image produced from print composer is accurate?

Comment: What are you using as your basemap? If you are using webmap (Google, Bing etc) imagery it may not export well.

Comment: Ah, okay. I'm using the Stamen Toner/OSM webmap, so that must be my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, not sure on specifics but I had trouble with the same thing, may be to do with web Mercator projection that web maps use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the OpenLayers plugin. Use the QuickMapServices plugin instead, as that works correctly with the map composer.

Comment: Perfect - thank you. I wasn't aware of this plugin and have now switched from the OpenLayers plugin. This fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've already had this problem with webmaps. I got a clean output by setting the same scale inside QGIS canvas and Print Composer.

In my case, misalignment came from scales being different between the two frames.
[image]